# Grouping excel cells in java

Tags: excel, java

I'm working with ms excel in java. Does anybody know how to group rows? Does POI or jxl have this feature? I searched through documentation but didn't manage to find an answer.

Comment: Please consider showing at least some of the code you are already using.

Comment: Actually I have no code right now. I have task to generate reports in excel and i need this feature. so i'm trying to figure out if it is possible and what i should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer. You need just call `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.groupRow()` method.